# Jenkins Plugin Development - Get IP Address of Hosts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm working on a Jenkins Node Dashboard plugin. Most of the information I've been interested in has been built into the **Computer** and **Node** classes. However, I can't seem to get any information on the IP address of the individual computers connected to the Jenkins master.

I've looked through the Computer class's documentation, and the closest I've been able to find to an IP is the getHostName() method, but this only returns the name of the machine, not the IP.

The slave machines connected to Jenkins use different Launch methods, but they all connect using the IP address in the Host field.

Answer (score 0):

Inside CliPort class there is a endpoint variable, which is of type InetSocketAddress.

InetSocketAddress has a getAddress() method which gives the InetAddress.

(An instance of an InetAddress consists of an IP address and possibly its corresponding host name (depending on whether it is constructed with a host name or whether it has already done reverse host name resolution). - From InetAddress Java 7 API)

```
clip.endpoint.getAddress() returns an IP address
```

Also, you could try :

```
InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName(address);
```

OR

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() - to get the localhost IP address
```